# In Prolog, how can I check condition B only if condition A is not satisfied?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to solve this optimization problem with Prolog.
A person can only drive a car if his/her ability is higher than the car's difficulty. Additionally, *if possible*, each person should get one of the cars in their wishlist (`favcar`).

I tried doing this using the `*->` operator and conditions `g1`, `g2` as shown below, but it doesn't work. The script simply checks `g1` and if it is not satisfied, as in the example below, it returns `false`.

If I change line 7 to `favcar(a, [1,3])`, for example, it works. But I also wanted to cover cases in which that is not possible.

```
car(1).
car(2).
car(3).
person(a).
person(b).
person(c).
favcar(a, [1]).
favcar(b, [1]).
favcar(c, [1,2]).
ability(a,0).
ability(b,1).
ability(c,2).
diff(1,0).
diff(3,0).
diff(2,1).
candrive(X,Y) :- ability(X,H1),diff(Y,H2),person(X),car(Y),H1>=H2.
wants(X,Y) :- favcar(X, L), member(Y,L), person(X),car(Y).
g1(X,Y) :- person(X),car(Y),candrive(X,Y),wants(X,Y).
g2(X,Y) :- person(X),car(Y),candrive(X,Y).
gen(X,Y) :- g1(X,Y) *-> g1(X,Y); g2(X,Y).
unique([]).
unique([X|Xs]) :-
    \+ memberchk(X, Xs),
    unique(Xs).
solve(C1,C2,C3) :- gen(a,C1),gen(b,C2),gen(c,C3),unique([C1,C2,C3]).
```

Comment: Usual reminder: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construct **(** *Condition* ***->** *Action* **;** *Else* **)** implements a [soft-cut](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(*-%3E)/2). The problem is that, when *Condition* succeeds at least **once**, *Else* is **never** executed. This can be observed with the following query:

```
?- (g1(X,Y) *-> g1(X,Y) ; g2(X,Y)).
X = a,
Y = 1 ;
X = b,
Y = 1 ;
X = c,
Y = 1 ;
X = c,
Y = 2 ;
false.
```

According to predicate `g1/2`, car `1` should be assigned to both `a` and `b`. However, as this is not allowed by predicate `unique/1`, no solution is found.

So, a possible solution would be to define a predicate to assign a car to each person (according to `candrive/2`) and to compute how many of them were satisfied (according to `wants/2`). The use of the predicate [select/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#select/3) guarantees that a same car will not be assigned to different people.

```
assignment([], _, [], 0).
assignment([P|Ps], Cs, [P-C|A], N) :-
    candrive(P, C),
    select(C, Cs, R),
    assignment(Ps, R, A, N0),
    (   wants(P, C)
    ->  N is N0 + 1      % satisfied!
    ;   N is N0 ).
```

**Feasible solutions**:

```
?- assignment([a,b,c], [1,2,3], A,  N).
A = [a-1, b-3, c-2],
N = 2 ;
A = [a-1, b-2, c-3],
N = 1 ;
A = [a-3, b-1, c-2],
N = 2 ;
A = [a-3, b-2, c-1],
N = 1 ;
false.
```

Finally, using this predicate, an optimal assignment can be obtained as follows:

```
best_assignment(A) :-
    findall(P, person(P), Ps),
    findall(C, car(C), Cs),
    assignment(Ps, Cs, A, W),         % A is a solution and
    \+ ( assignment(Ps, Cs, _, W1),   % there is no better one!
         W1 > W ).
```

**Optimal solutions**:

```
?- best_assignment(A).
A = [a-1, b-3, c-2] ;
A = [a-3, b-1, c-2] ;
false.
```